# plot data 2.5% percentiles 97.5% percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Im working with times series data so for SO purposes Ill make some up..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=10, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 10)}, index=rng)
```

If I plot this it looks like this: `df.plot()`

[image]

I can print the values of `df` upper and lower percentiles:
`df.quantile(0.025)`
`df.quantile(0.975)`

But how would I add lines to my chart to represent the 2.5th percentile and 97.5th percentile of the dataset?

Comment: check out `ax.hline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.axhline` for plotting a horizontal line at a specific Y value (conversively, there's `plt.axvline` for plotting a vertical line at a specific X value):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                       

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=10, freq='1H') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 10)}, index=rng)                                                                                                                   
df.plot()    

plt.axhline(df.quantile(0.025)[0])                                                                                                                                                    
plt.axhline(df.quantile(0.975)[0])                                                                                                                                                    

plt.show()
```

Plot produced:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=10, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 10)}, index=rng)

df.plot()
plt.hlines(df.quantile(0.025), xmin=min(rng), xmax=max(rng), linestyle="--", color="r")
plt.hlines(df.quantile(0.975), xmin=min(rng), xmax=max(rng), linestyle="--", color="r");
```

[image]